# Powershell - Count X of something in String

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Right so essentially I am storing a domain name into a variable - which then I need to split up later in my code into it's individual parts i.e.

```
$domainName = "testdomain.co.uk"
$domainNameSplit = $domainName.split(".")

echo $domainNameSplit[0]
echo $domainNameSplit[1]
echo $domainNameSplit[2]
```

In this instance it's fine as I know it's a .co.uk so will have 3 parts - however my code allows for input and therefore may take a `testdomain.local` format instead. How can I look through the $domainName variable and find the number of  `'.'` in order to know what to do with it?

I also need to then use it in order to create a `$ou` variable to work with, so:

```
$ou = "DC=WhatWouldIPutHere?,DC=AndHere"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the array length isn't enougth?

```
$domainName = "testdomain.co.uk"
$domainNameSplit = $domainName.split(".")

$domainNameSplitCount = $domainNameSplit.count
```

or to create a DN:

```
$domainName = "testdomain.co.uk"
$domainNameSplit = $domainName.split(".")
$a = [string]::empty
$domainNameSplit | % { $a+="DC=$_," }
$a.trim(',')
```

Comment: What does the $_ symbolise in this case? That has always confused me

Comment: `$_` is always the actual item processed in a pipe.

Comment: So the variable being used at the beginning of the pipeline?

Comment: `$$domainNameSplit` contains 3 string, the foresach-object process one string at time assigning the value to `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

Just another suggestion:

```
$domainName = "testdomain.co.uk"

# Get Count
$PartCount = $domainName.Split(".").Count

# Make an OU
$ou = "DC=" + $domainName -replace "\.", ",DC="
```